# google chrome won't download on windows 8

Tags: google-chrome

I have tried over and over, but chrome won't download.  it just stops, doesn't say why, no error code, just stops. sometimes says it's locating internet, then just stays there for hours if I let it.  sometimes stops at initial analysis, goes on forever, then does nothing.

Comment: 1. Which browser are you using to download? 2. Stops = Quits? 3. Can you give us the exact message it gives you rather than `locating internet`. 4. Have you downloaded the Chrome installer from Google's website? 5. Have you tried [this](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Chrome from a full installation package by clicking [here](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en):

> These alternate installers don’t require network connection to install Chrome, so you can install Chrome while being offline. Once installed, Chrome will attempt to automatically update whenever it detects that a newer version of the browser is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Offline installer with the latest version of chrome : [LINK](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html?standalone=1).